# highcharts - Hide some labels in yAxis

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I have a chart with a yAxis, that has a minimum of -5, and max of 5.

The yAxis has these labels: `-5`, `-2.5`, `0`, `2.5`, `5`.

My config is so close - I have the right amount of grid/plot lines, but I want to hide a couple of the *text labels* in the yAxis (*not* the actual lines relating to the label).

In other words, I want to remove or hide the `-2.5` and `2.5` labels.

I've tried various methods in the yAxis, eg step, but it's not achieving what I want.

```
yAxis: {
  labels: {
    step: 5
  }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/04f2ouu3/1/)

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I nearly didn't post this question because I found a (non-SO) answer - perhaps this will help others.

I don't know if this is the most elegant approach for highcharts, but you can use the label `formatter` to achieve this.

In my case, instead of this:

```
labels: {
  formatter: function () {
    return this.value+'%';
  }
}
```

We can add a conditional to check the label's value, and only return something if it's what we want. All together:

```
yAxis: {

  //...

  labels: {
    formatter: function () {

      if (this.value !== -2.5 && this.value !== 2.5) {
        return this.value+'%';
      }

    },
    step: 1
  },

  //...

},
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/anu964vr/1/)

Warning: hard coding some values and depending on them in this way is risky if you have dynamic data. For this instance we don't have dynamic data, they *will* be fixed, so it's safe for us. Another approach could be to iterate over each value/label and only return every X child as you require.